# Java 8 HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>

Tags: java, java-8

I am new Java 8 and want to sort a Map based on Key and then sort each list within values.

I tried to look for a Java 8 way to sort Keys and also value.
HashMap> map

```
map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
        Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

I am able to sort the Map and I can collect each values within map to sort but is their a way we can do in java 8 and can both be combined.

Comment: Use a `groupingBy` with a downstream `Collector`.

Comment: Maybe, you could use a TreeMap instead of a HashMap. TreeMaps order by key as a feature of the implementation.

Answer (score 4):

To sort by key, you could use a `TreeMap`. To sort each list in the values, you could iterate over the values of the map by using the `Map.values().forEach()` methods and then sort each list by using `List.sort`. Putting it all together:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> sortedByKey = new TreeMap<>(yourMap);

sortedByKey.values().forEach(list -> list.sort(null)); // null: natural order
```

This sorts each list *in-place*, meaning that the original lists are mutated.

---

If instead you want to create not only a new map, but also new lists for each value, you could do it as follows:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> sortedByKey = new TreeMap<>(yourMap);

sortedByKey.replaceAll((k, originalList) -> { 
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(originalList);
    newList.sort(null); // null: natural order
    return newList;
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the comments, you might want to change:

```
sortedByKey.values().forEach(list -> list.sort(null));
```

By either:

```
sortedByKey.values().forEach(Collections::sort);
```

Or:

```
sortedByKey.values().forEach(list -> list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Either one of the two options above is much more expressive and shows the developer's intention in a better way than using `null` as the comparator argument to the `List.sort` method.

Same considerations apply for the approach in which the lists are not modified in-place.

Comment: just a little cleaner with reference, you can use `sortedByKey.values().forEach(Collections::sort);` for natural order sorting of the list